# Determine where is the function $f(z)=z^{2}\overline{z}$ analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the points of complex plane, where the function is analytic $f(z)=z^{2}\overline{z}$.

My approach: Note that, $$\dfrac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \overline{z}}=z^{2}=0$$
this implies that $z=0$, is the only point where the function is analytic. This is correct?

Comment: By definition, a function can't be analytic at an isolated point, so the function is nowhere analytic.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z) = z^2 \overline{z} = z |z|^2$. Note $z$ is entire, so the set where $f$ is analytic is solely determined by $|z|^2$. For any neighborhood of any complex number $z$, this function ($|z|^2$) has zero imaginary part. Assume $f$ is analytic in some (open) set. Now, without loss of generality, assume our small neighborhood is connected, then we may conclude that this function itself is constant in that neighborhood, which is a contradiction.

Comment: At first, I thought you had misread the question, but actually the question was changed after your answer, in such a way that your answer no longer applies.

Comment: See the correction I made accordingly.

Comment: @S.D.ZHU First of all I apologize for searching for you here in a place where it is not supposed for me to comment here. But, please, help me with this? I only would like at least a hint, a small tip. Please, help me, I know from your profile that you are good at pde classic theory. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797950/what-hypothesis-can-i-assum-in-order-to-obtain-infinity-solutions-for-this-probl